# python csv don't print duplicates

Tags: python-2.7, csv, duplicates

We have many csv files as follows:

```
Name,Type
1,Fuji
2,Fuji
3,Fuji
4,Fuji
5,Washington
6,Washington
7,Washington
8,Washington
9,Washington
```

We would to print out the types of apples without printing duplicates.

```
Fuji:6  Washington:4 Gaza:1
```

Or

```
Fuji  Washington Gaza
```

The following is our attempt. Although it doesn't seem to work for unknown reasons.

```
# Python 2.7 
import csv

import glob

import collections

from collections import Counter

list = glob.glob('C:Apple*.csv')

for file in list:

infile = open(file, "rb")

reader = csv.reader(infile)   

    for column in reader:

    Discipline = column[1]

    print collections.Counter(Discipline)   

 infile.close()
```

Comment: You make *no attempt* to avoid duplicates. What have you tried, and what precisely went wrong? Do you have *any ideas* on how to proceed?

Comment: Sorry I post the wrong scripts.  Now I have updated it!  Thanks.

Comment: *"it doesn't seem to work for unknown reasons"* - do you think you could provide a less helpful "description" of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the `csv` module before but here is a quick attempt at what I think you might be trying to achieve.

```
import csv

src = r'C:\apples_before.csv'
dst = r'C:\apples_after.csv'

apples = set([])

# Read file.
with open(src, 'r') as srcfile:
    reader = csv.reader(srcfile, delimiter=',')
    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        if index == 0:
            continue

        apples.add(row[1])

# Write file. 
# @warning: Please note that I am making an assumption in terms of the number
# component. I am assuming it is a row number.
with open(dst, 'w') as dstfile:
    writer = csv.writer(dstfile, delimiter=',')
    for index, apple in enumerate(apples):
        if index == 0:
            writer.writerow(['Name', 'Type'])

        writer.writerow([index + 1, apple])
```

Comment: Thanks Yani for the solution and the detailed explanation.  I change the above input to csv.   Your script and our script above didn't generate any output file.   May I know if you might have any comment?  Thanks!

Comment: I have changed my answer based on what I think you are trying to achieve.